# How to change asc to desc in state?

Tags: reactjs

I need sort table by (asc-desc).
I have this state in hook(App.js file):

```
import Table from "./Table.js";

 const [value, setValue] = useState({
    list:[],
    sortAscDesc: "asc"
  });
```

I have method who change field `sortAscDesc`:

```
const changeSortAscDesc = () => {    
    setValue((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      sortAscDesc: ........
    }));
  };
```

**Question 1:**
What I must to write instead `........` in method `changeSortAscDesc`  that `"asc"` change to `"desc"`? Or how can I do this method correctly?

Also I have table(Table.js):

```
export default ({data, ..........}) => (
  <table className="table">
    <thead className="table-head">
      <tr>
        <th onClick={..........}>id</th>
        <th>title</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {data.map(item => (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          <td>{item.id}</td>
          <td>{item.title}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);
```

**Question 2:**
 Can I write here:
`export default ({data, ..........}) => (`
 `props` near the `data` instead `..........`?
Because I can not write only `props` since `data` present in my main copmponent:
`<Table data={value.list}/>`

**Question 3:**
 What I must to write instead `........` in this line:
`<th onClick={..........}>id</th>`?
Just sorting should be by clicking on the title `id`. It must look like this:

```
<th onClick={props.onSort.bind(null, "id")}> ID {props.sortField === "id" ? {props.sort} : null} </th>
```

**Question 4:**
 How dispaly `asc` near `id`? So that the user sees what sorting is now. `asc` or `desc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

---

```
 const changeSortAscDesc = () => {    
      setValue((prev) => ({
       ...prev,
       sortAscDesc: prev.sortAscDesc == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'
     }));
    };
```

---

2.

---

```
 export default ({data, ...props})
```

---

Will spread rest props inside, though you can also do just

---

```
     export default (props)
```

---

and inside `props.data` gonna evaluate to your data

And didn't exactly understand your third issue

Comment: third issue:
I must change my field `sortAscDesc` when I click on the header id. Its must look like this:
`<th onClick={props.onSort.bind(null, "id")}>
          ID {props.sortField === "id" ? <small>{props.sort}</small> : null}
        </th>`
Also see my four question, because I edit my question. Four question related to my third question

Comment: You can see in another application how work this event:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sortexample-63t0w?file=/src/Table/Table.js
But there is a different application logic

Comment: what exactly supposed to be trigger on click? because there description and sorting are changing when clicking on ID